# Problem in labeling edges of graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I am having problems in trying to label a graph containing mixed edges (directed and undirected edges). The simplest demonstration is based on an example in the documentation for `EdgeLabels` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeLabels.html):

We can create the following directed graph:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 2) -> "Label 1", (2 -> 3) ->  "Label 2", (3 -> 1) -> "Label 3"}]
```

or the following undirected graph:

```
g2 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeLabels -> {(1 <-> 2) -> "Label 1", (2 <-> 3) -> "Label 2", (3 <-> 1) -> "Label 3"}]
```

Both plot fine but when I mix directed and undirected edges I get no image appearing such as:

```
g3 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 <-> 1}, EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 2) -> "Label 1", (2 -> 3) -> "Label 2", (3 <-> 1) -> "Label 3"}]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a documented problem? In the Wolfram documentation there is a possible issue for labelling of directed edges but this seems to be resolved using parentheses. Does someone have a workaround for this?

Comment: It's is a bug,maybe you should report it.

Comment: Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> "Label 1", 
   DirectedEdge[2, 3] -> "Label 2", 3 <-> 1 -> "Label 3"}] works

Comment: @yode . Thanks for that, that also works (see also the answer of Anjan Kumar). These solutions seem somehow to be inconsistent with the documentation. I will report it.

Comment: Wolfram support just replied "After investigating, it seems that Mathematica does not accept the arrow syntax -> (Rule) as a valid representation of a label for a directed edge in a mixed graph. I will report a suggestion to add the syntax as acceptable for mixed graphs." The solution suggested by support is to use Directed Edge rather than Rule when using EdgeLabels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Property` wrapper can be used to set each edge label explicitly.

```
Graph[MapThread[
  Property[#1, EdgeLabels -> #2] &, {{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 
    3 <-> 1}, {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works, seems like there is a bit of confusion in the documentation for EdgeLabels about the difference between the use of DirectedEdge and Rule.